# Scala for comprehension to filter XML?

Tags: xml, scala

I want to be able to use the following to find a CD with the title:

```
val empire =
    cdPrices find { case( cd, _, _) =>
        cd == "Empire Burlesque"
    }

println(empire)
```

The above does not work because I get "constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type".

When I attempt the following alternate syntax, I get errors concerning the type:

```
val (empire, price, year) = cdPrices find (_._1 == "Empire Burlesque")
            getOrElse("Empire Burlesque", "10","1985")
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

My XML is as follows: http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/cd_catalog.xml

Comment: What is cdPrices, and how is it's value calculated. What "errors concerning the type". Details, details!

Comment: FOr me, the first code compiles. The second gives the "constructor cannot be..." error, but that's a precedence issue - add parens like this `(cdPrices find (_._1 == "Empire Burlesque"))` and it works. Marking to close as typographical error, as as far as I can see it's nothing to do with XML, or for comprehensions, just missing parens

Comment: Your getOrElse param should be in additional parens too as it need to be a tuple (the compiler does this for you, with a warning)

Comment: Can you not and are you not supposed to use the "case" parameter?

Comment: I don't understand that comment. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but maybe you are looking for something like this?

The following code returns `<CD><TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>....</CD>` if found, and returns `<CD><TITLE>Empire Burlesque Not Found</TITLE></CD>` if we cannot find the node.

```
val root = scala.xml.XML.loadFile("cd_catalog.xml")
val cd = (root \ "CD" ).find{x => (x \ "TITLE").text == "Empire Burlesque"}
                  .getOrElse{<CD><TITLE>Empire Burlesque Not Found</TITLE></CD>}
println(cd)
```

Check for
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.xml.Elem for what `\` operator means, and also `\\` is convenient when you what to search recursively.

Comment: Can you not and are you not supposed to use the "case" parameter?

Comment: If you use `{case x=>..}` it would be a `PartialFunction`, which is subclass of `scala.Function1`. In this case you may use `{case x=>}`. but it is not necessary. see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction for more detail.